# Palindrome in Java with NUmbers

Tags: java, loops, while-loop, palindrome

I am self studying java, i am on while loops already, I have an exercise here regarding a palindrome. what's a palindrome? how will code it? any ideas? or pseudocode for it? I am really confused here

NOT a HOMEWORK

Comment: Perhaps have a look at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Palindrome

Answer (score 1):

Since its not homework, it shouldn't matter how you implement it.

```
public static <ToStringable> boolean isPalindrome(ToStringable stringable) {
    String text = stringable.toString();
    return text.equals(new StringBuilder(text).reverse().toString());
}
```

Comment: `ToStringable`? Every object is `toString()`-able.

Comment: In the example if you override the toString() and return a null a NPE occur. So I guess that's why he says "ToStringable".

Comment: Its just a comment. Every class has a `toString()` method, but not every class has a useful `toString()` e.g. `[C@ef127a0`

Answer (score 0):

A palindrome is a sequence that reads the same backwards as forwards, like "kayak" or 12321.

See here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Palindrome

EDIT: there are also lots of questions about palindromes on stackoverflow already. Browse through them and come back if you have more specific questions:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/palindrome

Answer (score 0):

Palindrome is a sequence such that reversing the sequence gives you the same sequence. E.g. MAM